# How do I make a clickable shortcut to open a random shortcut file in a dir on Linux?

Tags: scripting, linux-mint, desktop-shortcuts

I have made a directory on my Linux Mint desktop called "Ungoogled Chromium shortcuts". It contains one `.desktop` file per proxy I have access to.

If I open this directory and double-click one of the shortcuts in there, it opens Ungoogle Chromium with the correct `--proxy` setting.

Now I'm trying to make it so that, instead of manually opening the directory and picking one of the shortcuts, I can just click a shortcut directly on the desktop to open one of those shortcuts at random.

How would I accomplish this? (Without installing any extra software.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414164/how-can-i-select-random-files-from-a-directory-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from my research, it appears this is more likely to work if you name the folder `applications` rather than `Ungoogled Chromium shortcuts`. You can make it a subfolder named `applications` in `Ungoogled Chromium shortcuts`. So create such a subfolder and move the `.desktop` files in there, I'm assuming this is `$HOME/Ungoogled Chromium shortcuts/applications`.

Now, first we need to create a shell script.

Open a terminal. First create a folder to place the shell script in. If you don't have a place already you can use `~/bin`.

`mkdir ~/bin`

Now let's edit a file in that folder. You can use whatever text editor you want, and name the file whatever you want. But I'm assuming `nano` and the file is `random-shortcut-launcher.sh`, so do:

`nano ~/bin/random-shortcut-launcher.sh`

Now paste in the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYFOLDER="$HOME/Ungoogled Chromium shortcuts"
XDG_DATA_HOME="$MYFOLDER" gtk-launch "$(basename "$(find "$MYFOLDER/applications/"*.desktop | shuf -n 1)")"
```

Save and exit. (ctrl-O then ctrl-X if you're using nano)

Now make the script executable:

`chmod a+x ~/bin/random-shortcut-launcher.sh`

Now let's create a new `.desktop` file. If you want it to show up in menus, place it in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`. (It might work if you put it in the Desktop folder; I haven't tried.) If you have a `.desktop` file editor, you can use that, but you can also create one with a text editor:

`nano $HOME/.local/share/applications/ShortcutLauncher.desktop`

Paste in:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=MyRandomShortcutLauncher
GenericName=My random shortcut launcher
Exec=/home/<username>/bin/random-shortcut-launcher.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network
Comment=Whatever you want
```

Change `<username>` in `Exec=` to your actual username. Change `/path/to/icon.png` in `Icon=` to some actual png file you want to use as the icon. Change "whatever you want" in `Comment=` to whatever you want, and similarly for `Name=` and `GenericName=`

You might want to change `Network` under `Categories=` depending on what part of the menu you want this in. See [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html#category-registry).

Save and exit.

Should work. But if it doesn't, don't just write "not working". Tell us what you did and what happens when you try this.

Comment: Not working... It doesn't even understand what Bash is.

Comment: I don't know how you can say it's not working when you don't even know how to do what I recommended, but I'll edit my answer.